# What is the best recommended way to deploy the ARM Templates into Azure

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Am working on ARM Templates. I developed some ARM templates like:

- SQL Server
- ServicePlan
- ServiceBus
- StorageAccount

etc.

I Am missing the sequence of deploying. For that, I searched and known that there is two ways for this issue i.e., using “**depends on** and **manifest.json** ” concept.

What is the enterprise recommended way to deploy the Azure ARM templates?

Comment: Sounds a lot like this similar question at the same time... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859908/which-one-is-first-deploy-on-resources

Answer (score 0):

There is no real 'recommended' way of deploying ARM templates. As far as I'm aware all of the programming languages, (as well as the REST interface) have a method for deploying a template.

The idea is that you can choose what you already have, authenticate to Azure via the tools you already use, and deploy a template.

For instance, my current solution has a few methods for deploying templates. While I am developing templates, I am typically developing them on either Linux or Windows, so will use either the Azure Cli, or Azure Powershell to deploy them directly.

Once a template is developed and tested, it is pushed into blob storage, where it can be picked up via our deployment mechanism. This mechanism either sits in our CI environment (currently Saltstack) or it runs on Azure Automation. For either of those methods a script will go and collect variables for whichever environment they are being pushed to, pass them in and deploy.